# Proguard Change String Request Variable name when send to Server

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am Using string Request when I create a Signapk Proguard Change name of the variable is in a b c d e f How I can handle it
it is only an issue in one request all other requests working fine in this request I am using GSON
Here is my Code

senditems_ is an array list that contains 5 records of students

```
String studentBatchListString = new Gson().toJson(send_items_);
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError { 
   Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
   Log.i("timessendreq","send");                    
   parameters.put("list_items",studentBatchListString);
   return parameters;
}
```

I am using volley string request My Class name is (Checkoutinfo)
pakege name is com.app.trasfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep User Student Object By add @Keep annotation Top of yor class, Something like below

```
@Keep
class Student{
int id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to solve it

1. Use the annotations in the code and add proper proguard configuration

Field serialized name

```
@SerializedName("keyType")
String keyType;
```

proguard configuration

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.google.gson.annotations.**
```

2. If you dont want to use the annotation, then you need to exclude the class from obfuscation

   ```
   -keepclassmembers class com.example.app.YourClass{
        public protected private *;
        #Keep default members & functions
        !public !protected !private *;
    }
   ```

Comment: I don't understand it can you please write  it in 2nd method my class and packegename is mention in question and my string array key variable is also in request

Comment: -keepclassmembers class com.app.trasfer.Checkoutinfo{
     public protected private *;
     #Keep default members & functions
     !public !protected !private *;
 }